# What simple groups have irreducible characters of degree 4 or 5?

Tags: gr.group-theory

The only simple groups having an irreducible character of degree 3 are $A_5$ and $PSL_2(7)$. What is it know for degrees 4 or 5? That is, do we know what simple groups posses an irreducible charcter of degree 4? of degree 5?

Comment: I'm reminded of this www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTby_e4-Rhg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best modern source for this information is the paper:

G. Hiss and G. Malle.
Low-dimensional representations of quasi-simple groups.
LMS J. Comput. Math. 4 (2001), 22-63.
Corrigenda: LMS J. Comput. Math. 5 (2002), 95-126.

This lists all irreducible representations (in characteristic 0 and coprime to the defining characteristic of the group, if any) of all finite quasisimple groups (perfect groups with $G/Z(G)$ simple) up to dimension 250.

Answer (score 11):

You can consult the ATLAS to see that the sporadic groups don't figure here.

For groups of Lie type you should refer to the following paper:

> V. Landazuri and G.M. Seitz, *On the minimal degrees of projective representations of the finite Chevalley groups*, J. Algebra **32** (1974), 418-443.

There are actually a couple of errors in the main theorem of this paper, and a correct version is given as Table 5.3.A. of Kleidman and Liebeck's *The subgroup structure of the finite classical groups*.

Finally the alternating groups are dealt with in Proposition 5.3.7 of Kleidman and Liebeck; in particular you'll see that only $A_5, A_6$ and $A_7$ are relevant here.

Note that all of these reults give **projective representations**; these will all lift to representations of a quasisimple cover of the relevant simple group. To check whether this quasisimple cover is actually the simple group in question you can use the ATLAS.

Note that I have e-copies of all the sources I've referenced and will email you copies if you need them.

**Update**: Out of interest, I went through the sources above to see which groups have nontrivial irreducible reps of degree at most 5 and they are:
$$A_5, A_6, PSL_2(7), PSL_2(11), PSp_4(3).$$
You should, of course, check that I haven't missed any!

Comment: note that $A_6\simeq PSL_2(9)$.

Comment: good point, editing now.